# Using \b in C# regular expressions doesn't work?

Tags: c#, regex, word-boundary

I am wondering why the following regex does not match.

```
string query = "\"1 2\" 3";
string pattern = string.Format(@"\b{0}\b", Regex.Escape("\"1 2\""));
string repl = Regex.Replace(query, pattern, "", RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
```

Note that if I remove the word boundary characters (\b) from `pattern`, it matches fine. Is there something about '\b' that might be tripping this up?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I just want to remove words from a string, as simple as that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quote is not a word character, so \b will not be a match if it is there.  There is no word character before the quote; so, before the quote, there is no transition between word characters and non-word characters.  So, no match.

From your comment you are trying to remove word characters from a string.  The most straightforward way to do that would be to replace `\w` with an empty string:

```
string repl = Regex.Replace(query, "\w", "", RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
```

Comment: I'm trying to remove words (which I read from a file), not word characters. I'm now using 
`string pattern = string.Format(@"(^|\W+){0}(\W+|$)", Regex.Escape("\"1 2\""));` 
which seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

you are expecting a whitespace.
it isn't finding one.
replace

```
string query = "\"1 2\" 3";
```

with

```
string query = "\" 1 2 \" 3";
```

and you'll see what i mean.